# Store an array in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

i'm new to Java. How can i store an array of integers values in a HashMap, after that i write this HashMap in a txt file  but this isn't important at the moment. I can store single fields but not an array. Any ideas ?

```
public void salveazaObiectulCreat(String caleSpreFisier) {

    HashMap map = new HashMap();

    map.put ("Autorul",numelePrenumeleAutorului);
    map.put ("Denumirea cartii",denumireaCartii);
    map.put ("Culoarea cartii",culoareaCartii);
    map.put ("Genul cartii",gen);
    map.put ("Limba",limba);
    map.put ("Numarul de copii",numarulDeCopii);
    map.put ("Numarul de pagini",numarulDePagini);
    map.put ("Pretul cartii",pretulCartii);

  try  {

      File file = new File(caleSpreFisier);  

      FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);  

      ObjectOutputStream s = new ObjectOutputStream(f);          

      s.writeObject(map);

      s.close();

       } catch(Exception e){

           System.out.println("An exception has occured");     
    }   
}
```

Comment: An array of what integers?  Are you trying to put multiple arrays into the HashMap?

Comment: There should be no difference between arrays and any other objects. What did you try?

Comment: those values in map.put are Strings, now i want to store an array of int values(some digits)

Comment: We will need to see the rest of the code, for example what `numelePrenumeleAutorului` is.

Comment: @biziclop i tried with a for statments , somethig like this : for (int i=0;i<numarulDeCopii;i++) {
    
        map.put(i, coeficientUzura[i]);
    }

Comment: Look here which seems to be a copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602665/store-an-array-in-hashmap

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
HashMap<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
HashMap<String, int[]> map = new HashMap<String, int[]>();
```

pick one, for example

```
HashMap<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
map.put("Something", new ArrayList<Integer>());
for (int i=0;i<numarulDeCopii; i++) {
    map.get("Something").add(coeficientUzura[i]); 
}
```

or just

```
HashMap<String, int[]> map = new HashMap<String, int[]>();
map.put("Something", coeficientUzura);
```

Comment: if you get the value in recyclerview as like subject .getsubject(); in adapter class then how it should be implemented

Answer (score 37):

Not sure of the exact question but is this what you are looking for?

```
public class TestRun
{
     public static void main(String [] args)
     {
        Map<String, Integer[]> prices = new HashMap<String, Integer[]>();

        prices.put("milk", new Integer[] {1, 3, 2});
        prices.put("eggs", new Integer[] {1, 1, 2});
     }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the Map interface will allow you to store Arrays as values.  Here's a very simple example:

```
int[] val = {1, 2, 3};
Map<String, int[]> map = new HashMap<String, int[]>();
map.put("KEY1", val);
```

Also, depending on your use case you may want to look at the [Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) support offered by [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store multiple values for a key (if I understand you correctly), you could try a [MultiHashMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiHashMap.html) (available in various libraries, not only commons-collections).

Answer (score 0):

Your life will be much easier if you can save a List as the value instead of an array in that Map.

Answer (score 0):

You can store objects in a HashMap.

`HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();`

You'll just need to cast it back out correctly.