# how pass to array from function to dependent functions

Tags: java

I have table like this:

```
alphabet     binery      integer      d(in rad sin(integer)*100         e       f
a1            1010       10           41                              70.6     46.3
a2            0011       3            14                              57.06    37
```

I have created 4 functions that is: void alpha_int(), int binery( int a), float d( int x), float e(float b), float f(float f).
My one array is revolving in each function, firstly i am doing index wise for calculation up to function e(), but i am failed how to send complete array to function f() because it is taking avg.

code strtgy:

```
//----------------
//skipped theportion
//.............
void alpha_int()
{
    int [] a = new int [100];

    for(int i=1; i<=6;i++){
    {
       System.out.print("a"+i+"  "+binery(arra[i])+" "+array[i]+" "+d(array[i])+" "+e(d(array[i])));
    }

  f(a(d(array));   // gives error 
}
int binery( int a){
 // successfully complete
  return a;
}
float d( int x){
// did som work 
 return x;

}
 float e(float b){
// operations peformed
   return b;
}

 float f(float f){   // problem in sending complete array
     for( int i=1; i<f.length;i++){
         for(int j=1;j<f,length;j++){
            f[i]= f[i]+f[j]; 
         }
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you've defined the argument to be of type `float`, which is a single 32-bit floating point number, not an array. Try defining it as `float[]` or `int[]` instead.

Also, you must `return` something in `f`, as the function's type is defined to be `float`.

Comment: i did this it is now giving me error cannot cast from int[] to float in function d(); i in d() function i am doing like this: float array  = (float)x;

Comment: @user3508182, you need to have correct return types for all functions, naturally. If you have a call like `a(b(c(d)))`, `a` must accept the return value of `b` as an argument, `b` must accept the return value of `c` as an argument and `c` must accept `d` as an argument.

Comment: surely m doing this. but i cannot place f(a(d(array)); inside for loop in void alpha_int(); just give idea how shell i send complete "e" (from table ) to  f(...) function???

Comment: complete e means all values in array of function e()?

Comment: `e` returns just one float. Make it return the entire array if that's what you want. Alternatively, make your call different (put it in a loop).

Answer (score 0):

> My one array is revolving in each function,

You are storing data of various types into one array? You can instead go for a `HashMap<>` and use key-value pairs. Your methods can then retrieve different arrays based on on keys. Like so:

```
HashMap<String, int[]> map = new HashMap<String, int[]>();
```

and then work with it as:

```
binary( map.get("binary") );
```

later, set your result as :

```
map.put("binary",yourArrayName);  
return someValueBasedOnComputation;
```

Looks much cleaner, in my limited knowledge :)
Source: [Store an array in HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602665/store-an-array-in-hashmap)